# Can a technological bachelor apply for a master degree course in a first class US university?

Tags: masters, application, united-states

If a [technological bachelor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Technology) <s>technologist</s> has the necessary funding to the tuition fees, some years of work experience, excellent GPA/TOEFL/GRE/recommendation letters, can she/he apply for a master degree course in a top american university (such as MIT, UC Berkeley, Stanford, etc) and compete in the normal process?

**EDIT**

For example, in Brazil they call this degree *tecnólogo*, but in many countries it could be equivalent to a [Bachelor of Technology or B.Tech.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Technology) In my specific case, it is a [Bachelor of Information Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Information_Technology).

Comment: i s'pose it depends on the discipline.  if you were in some Electronics Technology field with, perhaps, a 2-year degree, to be useful in an Electrical Engineering graduate program you would possibly need some serious theoretical study in advanced mathematics and in systems theory.  EETs might not understand the Fourier Transform as deeply as EEs or other engineers/physics/math graduates do.

Comment: It's a 4-year degree (20 hours/week) named "Information Technology".

Comment: For something like this (that's fairly institution-specific, I personally feel), you're probably better off contacting the admission departments at these universities and asking them directly than you are asking random strangers on the internet :) They'll be able to help you see if your 4-year degree prepared you for their respective curricula.

Comment: And, to follow up on @tonysdg comment, they can also point out any specific courses they would want you to have had, and places to take them (either there or, say, at a local community college).

Comment: I'm rather confused by this question: what does "technologist" mean in this context, and how are they distinct from other students?

Comment: I've added more information. Could it be re-open? @jakebeal? professor Brian?

Comment: @VictorF It currently has three votes to reopen, including mine.  Hopefully two more will agree.

Comment: "Can you apply to an MS degree in a US university?" and "Can you apply to an MS degree in a first class US university?" are two different questions. I am willing to vote to re-open the former but not the latter because first class university requires more qualifications. Do you have excellent GPA? Do you have excellent TOEFL and GRE scores? Do you have excellent recommendation letters?

Comment: OK @scaaahu but now I need to know what is "excellent" GPA and how to get excellent recommendation letters ^^

Comment: How does one vote to re-open?

Comment: @VictorF - The edits don't address the original problem, which was that you really need to contact each university individually to find out the answer to this question. There is no universal answer to this question. That said, the question will stay here, and if the community feels that it should be re-opened they will vote that way.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique - See the [privileges](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page, after you gain a certain amount of reputation you can vote on individual questions.

Comment: Guys, thank you for votes. I'd like to see this question reopened soon, as I provided the necessary information .